# Conversion Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table with 2 columns

```
1. start_hr as smallint
2. Start_min as varchar(2)
```

i need to convert to time how to do

i have convert it too varchar and then tried to convert as time but didn't work

Table Name: DateTime_Table

[image: Table]

[image]

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Out of interest, why would you store the hour in a numeric column but the minute in a textual column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, start_hr * 60*60+start_min*60, 0), 108) 
from   table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you could:

1. Concatenate the separate columns into a string that looks like a time
2. Convert the string to a `TIME`
3. Conver the `TIME` to a `varchar` in the format you want
4. Trim the leading space that is added

The code is:

```
SELECT  start_hr, Start_min, LTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT( TIME, CONCAT(start_hr, ':', Start_min)), 22)) AS Output
  FROM  #DateTime_Table
```

This outputs:

```
start_hr Start_min Output
-------- --------- ------------
9        45        9:45:00 AM
13       25        1:25:00 PM
19       52        7:52:00 PM
23       12        11:12:00 PM
```

If you are **desperate to get rid of the seconds** you need to add a fifth step:

5. Extract the parts of the output string you want

The code for this a little bit more:

```
SELECT  start_hr,
        Start_min,
        CONCAT(LEFT(Output, LEN(Output) - 6), RIGHT(Output, 3)) AS Output
  FROM  (
        SELECT  start_hr, Start_min, LTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT( TIME, CONCAT(start_hr, ':', Start_min)), 22)) AS Output
          FROM  #DateTime_Table
        ) a
```

Output:

```
start_hr Start_min Output
-------- --------- ---------------
9        45        9:45 AM
13       25        1:25 PM
19       52        7:52 PM
23       12        11:12 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be like below :

```
select CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(CAST(Start_hr as varchar),':'), Start_min) as time)
              FROM DateTime_Table
```

Check result here : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/085c2/5)

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012+, you may try to use `TIMEFROMPARTS()` function to return a fully initialized time value:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    start_hr smallint,
    start_min varchar(2)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
    (start_hr, start_min)
VALUES
    (9, '45'),
    (12, '1'),
    (23, '18')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    TIMEFROMPARTS(start_hr, CONVERT(numeric(2, 0), start_min), 0, 0, 0) AS TimeValue,
    CONVERT(varchar, TIMEFROMPARTS(start_hr, CONVERT(numeric(2, 0), start_min), 0, 0, 0), 109) AS ConvertValue
FROM #Data
```

Output:

```
TimeValue   ConvertValue
09:45:00    9:45:00AM
12:01:00    12:01:00PM
23:18:00    11:18:00PM
```